# mkdir bin lib lib/NAME test The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Tags: command-line, mkdir

I am working through "Learn Ruby the Hard Way" and I'm stuck on exercise 46.  I have searched but because I know so little about the command prompt it is hard to refine my query to get an answer.

Here is the code I'm trying to execute and the response:

```
mkdir bin lib lib/NAME test
The syntax of the command is incorrect
```

Also I try to enter the following to also receive an error.

```
touch lib/NAME.rb
touch lib/NAME/version.rb
'touch' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Is this some sort of configuration issue?

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

For the first command it seems that you would have to enter the full address of the directory you are creating so you would need to enter

```
sudo mkdir /bin/lib/lib/NAME/test
```

As far as your second issue, are you sure that you have touch installed globally? Search for it with the command

```
sudo find / -name touch
```

and make sure it is installed in a folder like /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin.  If it is not, than move it to one of those folders to have global access to it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the intent is to create subirectories named `bin`, `lib` etc as subdirectories of the current directory. If that is the case, the advice to force the issue with `sudo` is misdirected and potentially dangerous -- you could create quite a mess if you muck around with root privileges without understanding what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use Unix commands at a Windows prompt. Upgrade to a Unix-compatible OS, install and learn Cygwin, or switch to a Windows-oriented tutorial.